# Spring sftp file polling in specific time

Tags: spring-integration

How to configure Spring `sftp:inbound-channel-adapter` to run between specific timing lets say 8am-7pm. 
Currently i just have the below configuration and i need to poll only between 8am-7pm 
`<int:poller fixed-rate="300000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />`.Heard that Spring batch would help. any suggestions ?

Comment: i added the following code `<int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" cron="0 0/5 8-17 * * *"/>` . But it is polling continuously out of the hours mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

Please, be more specific. Describe your requirements in human words.

E.g. you need to poll every 5 min starting from 8am and ending on 7pm every day.

In this case the cron will look like:

```
0 0/5 8-19 * *
```